# Change /wp-admin url for security and forgot what I put instead... where to find the info?

Tags: wordpress

I changed my `/wp-admin` url to access my config dashboard through a plug-in. Unfortunately, I crashed my laptop and lost the info on what I put instead.

Any idea where I can find the info on phpmyadmin or root files? or restore `/wp-admin`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do two things here.

First one is to check in the database and the second one is to backup the site and then delete the plugin and check if it's all like it was before.

The first way to do it is quite simple, and it is well described here: https://web.archive.org/web/20191219035208/http://wordpress.shadowlantern.com/how-change-wordpress-url-phpmyadmin

1. First log into PHPMyAdmin.
2. Select your desired database then click the browse icon for the options table
3. Look for the option_name of siteurl and click the little pencil(edit) icon.
4. Change the URL in the option_value field, but do not change anything else. (Do *not put a slash after the URL.) Then click “Go”.
5. Look for the home option_name and click the little pencil icon
6. Change the URL in the option_value field, but do not change anything else. (Do *not put a slash after the URL.) Then click “Go”.